# Find the first four non-zero terms of the power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

My professor said not to bother multiplying out term-by-term but instead use an identity to simplify the $f(x)$

The given is 
$$f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
I'm guessing what my prof. wants us to use is the Pythagorean Identity but that involves $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=0$ and I can't figure out how that's useful here. Also I don't know what he means by the first four non-zero terms of the series.
I am very lost when it comes to power series as the virus has restricted the availability of my professor to answer questions.

Comment: Consider $(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2=1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)$. The left hand side is easier than the multiplication, and its square could be computable by using the representation with the exponential function.

Comment: Or use $\sin(2x) + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sin(x)\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\\\\
\displaystyle\sin(z) = z - \frac{z^{3}}{3!} +  \frac{z^{5}}{5!} - \frac{z^{7}}{7!} + \ldots
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$. Use he power series for $\sin(t)$ with $t$ replaced by $2x$ and multiply the result by $\frac{1}{2}.$