# Find the first four non-zero terms of the power series for $f(x) = \sin x \cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

The given function is 
$$f(x)= \sin (x) \cos (x)$$
Now first we rewrite the function, knowing that $ \sin x \cos x=\frac{1}{2}(2\sin(x)\cos(x))$ we can now rewrite our given into:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$$
Then if we see the maclaurin series of $\sin(x)$ is:
$$\sin(x)=x -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+....$$
Then manipulating this series into our given results in the series being:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[2x+\frac{(2x)^{3}}{3!}-\frac{(2x)^{5}}{5!}-\frac{(2x)^{7}}{7!} \right]$$ 
$$f(x)=x-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5-\frac{4}{315}x^7+...$$

Am I correct in my calculations?

Comment: Your final answer looks right, but in the expression prior to it you should be careful and parenthesize the $2x$ terms, as right now it looks like, e.g., $2\cdot (x^3)$ instead of $(2x)^3$.

Comment: The same question has been asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640579/find-the-first-four-non-zero-terms-of-the-power-series

Comment: @user1337 I know that was me, I asked it again but provided my work this time, instead of just asking for help.

Comment: Dear @EricBrown, it is advisable to ask each question just once. Next time, you can edit the body of the question in order to provide your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin(x)=x -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+....$$
You forgot the factorial at the denominator and the power of $2$:
$$\sin(2x)=2x -\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}-\frac{2^7x^7}{7!}+....$$
$$\frac 12\sin(2x)=x -\frac{2^2x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^4x^5}{5!}-\frac{2^6x^7}{7!}+....$$
$$\frac 12\sin(2x)=x -\frac{2x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}-\frac{4x^7}{315}+....$$